# using taglist plugin in gvim on windows

Tags: windows, vim, ctags

im started using taglist plugin in gvim on windows7(64bit)

here is the path

```
path of ctags: C:\ctags58
path of gvim: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73
```

when i typed TlistToggle, i got following error message.

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>17_Tlist_WIndow_Toggle..<SNR>17_Tlist_Window_Open..<SNR>17_Tlist_Window_Refresh..<SNR>17_Tlist_Window_Refresh_File..<SNR>17_Tlist_Process_File:
E484: Can't open file C:/Users/*username*/AppData/Local/Temp/VIo9212.tmp
Taglist: Failed to generate tags for *path of test.cpp*
E484: Can't open file C:/Users/*username*/AppData/Local/Temp/VIo935B.tmp
Taglist: Failed to generate tags for *path of makefile*
```

is this slash/backslash problem?

if so, how can i solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Check your `shell` and `shellcmdflag` options.

```
:set shell?
:set shellcmdflag?
```

I ran into the same issues. I had Cygwin installed on my Windows machine, but I wasn't running Gvim under it. Yet, for some reason, the `shell` option was set to `/bin/bash`, which is obviously wrong, and so of course it couldn't actually run the ctags tool. I had to add the overrides to my `_vimrc` like so:

```
set shell=cmd.exe
set shellcmdflag=/C
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is my settings in .vimrc for the different environment I have:

```
if has("unix") " For environment at work (compiled locally)
  let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = "~/mytools/bin/ctags"
elseif has("win32")
  let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd="C:/cygwin/bin/ctags.exe"
elseif has("win32unix") " For Cygwin
  let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd="/usr/bin/ctags"
endif
```

You could try to give the path to ctags in thi way with `Tlist_Ctags_Cmd`
Hope this help.